# Android SDK can't update and AVD not detect CPU/ABI

Tags: android, macos, visual-studio, sdk, android-sdk-manager

I have two problems with Android SDK and emulator.

1. The *Android Virtual Device (AVD) Manager* not detect my system API 25 image. [Android Virtual Device Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoEDZ.png)
2. AndroidSdkManager always has 2 pending updates. They always return to the opening. They are : *Android SDK Platform Tools* and *Google Apis ARM EABI v7a System Image*

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

For your first issue you need to download system image for your target sdk.

Try this below url (How to Install and Run the Android Emulator):-

https://www.petefreitag.com/item/763.cfm

You need to focus on Step 3.

Comment: I read that the "android" command was obsolete. Other solution ?